# Handling empty EditText with toast

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, toast, string

So this is the code i got so far:

```
Button calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText sun = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sun1);
            EditText mon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mon1);
            EditText tue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tue1);
            EditText wed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wed1);
            EditText thu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.thu1);
            EditText fri = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fri1);
            EditText sat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sat1);
            EditText wage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wage);

            double sun1 = Double.parseDouble(sun.getText().toString());
            double mon1 = Double.parseDouble(mon.getText().toString());
            double tue1 = Double.parseDouble(tue.getText().toString());
            double wed1 = Double.parseDouble(wed.getText().toString());
            double thu1 = Double.parseDouble(thu.getText().toString());
            double fri1 = Double.parseDouble(fri.getText().toString());
            double sat1 = Double.parseDouble(sat.getText().toString());
            double wage1 = Double.parseDouble(wage.getText().toString());
            TextView hours = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hours);
            TextView income = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Income);  
            if(wage.getText().length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter the wage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
            Calculator calc = new Calculator(sun1,mon1,tue1,wed1,thu1,fri1,sat1,wage1);
            hours.setText(calc.hours()+"");
            income.setText(calc.calc()+"");
            }
```

As you can see, I want to display a toast whenever the user leaves any field empty. In this case, I have used only wage object to show where I am failing. I have also tried wage.getText().toString().equals("") and still my app crashes. Maybe it is the toast class that i am getting wrong. Using (this) instead of getContext() in the maketoast doesn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, use `TextUtils.isEmpty` to check if a string is empty.

Comment: I think at first move all the above code inside `onCreate` and outside `onClickListener`, since it seems to be using wrong context to get the `findViewByID`. : `EditText sun = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sun1);
            EditText mon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mon1);
            EditText tue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tue1);
            EditText wed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wed1);
            EditText thu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.thu1);..` Also the textView definition.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error, because your `findViewById(...)` isn't bound to the correct `this`. It should be outside of the `onClick` listener.

Typically, I would do something like the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText sun;
private EditText mon;
private EditText tue;
private EditText wed;
private EditText thu;
private EditText fri;
private EditText sat;
private EditText wage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    instantiateViews();
}

private void instantiateViews() {

    sun  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sun1);
    mon  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mon1);
    tue  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tue1);
    wed  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wed1);
    thu  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thu1);
    fri  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fri1);
    sat  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sat1);
    wage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wage);
}

//Write whatever other code you would here
}
```

Also, I recommend you use `TextUtils.isEmpty` over your current method to check that `wage` is empty.